# why doesn't datagridview refresh?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

here is what happens after i press a button:

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(some_query);
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

please note that i am doing this with another control called `chart1` and it works fine with it, it populates it with the new requeried data, but `datagridview` is just staying the same

the first attempt is successful.

however the second time i press it, it display the same thing!

anyone know whether i am refreshing the datagridview correctly?

Comment: Is `ConnectandReadList` returning different data?

Comment: @gmcalab yes definitely,

Comment: What *exactly* does that method return. And: are you on the UI thread at the time?

Comment: I admit the Refresh method on the `DataGridView` looks like it may refresh the data but it actually "Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls." `BindingSoure` all the way! I have commented lots on this page but most of these answers don't address the aformentioned `Refresh()` method which is the wrong thing to use and it's just more code to clear the `DataGridView` and set it again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little trick you can do if you are binding to a List<> when setting it to your data source add ToList() on it at the end like this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(some_query).ToList();
```

For some reason this causes it to refresh without loosing any references or anything.

An alternative is to directly notify the DataGridView that its data changed like this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(some_query)
var m = dataGridView1.GetType().GetMethod("OnDataSourceChanged", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
m.Invoke(dataGridView1, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
```

Comment: Can anyone offer insights to the ToList() and why it works?

Answer (score 13):

Subtle difference here to @Fake but calling `Refresh()` won't work as calling this on the  dataGridView only

> "Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls."

As this method relates to any control, not to the refresh of the data relating to an object. Refer [here (DataGridView Methods)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx48ebw.aspx) and scroll down to Refresh and you will see the link points to Control.Refresh Method

You want something like this;

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); 
bs.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(some_query);
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
bs.ResetBindings(false)
```

and then you can just call `ResetBindings()` on `bs` (Your `BindingSource`);

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); 
private refreshData()
{
    bs.ResetBindings(false)
}
```

Comment: ResetBindings FTW. There are a lot of listed suggestions for questions like this, but this is the only one I've got to work for a databound datagridview. This should be the answer as the accepted answer links to a forum post with no resolution...

Answer (score 1):

A DataGridView sets up bindings the first time you assign the DataSource. The problem is that subsequent DataSource assignments, if the assignments have a different structure from the initial assignment, will fail because the bindings are now "off"

You need to reset the DataGridView [thusly](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread256055.html) so that the data is bound a new. (The link is for VB but you just need to know the methods to call. Even copy/paste would be overkill.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling `EndEdit()` before `Refresh()` ?

Comment: Refresh() isn't what they need in this case I believe http://stackoverflow.com/a/14501458/427684

Answer (score 0):

You could do as @cycl suggested, you could also use a BindingSource which I believe is the recommended method by microsoft.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); 
bs.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(some_query);
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
dataGridView1.Refresh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is here that your TableAdapter is not refreshing.
I used this code after editing table (mydatabase.tbl) to refresh it:

```
            tblTableAdapter.Fill(mydatabaseDataSet.tbl);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tblBindingSource;
            dataGridView1.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code loads data into the `wMP_EXPORTDataSet.DEST_AX_PRICEDISCADMTRANSENTITY` table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

```
this.dEST_AX_PRICEDISCADMTRANSENTITYTableAdapter.Fill(this.wMP_EXPORTDataSet.DEST_AX_PRICEDISCADMTRANSENTITY);
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you initializing the datasource the first time in an `if(!Page.IsPostback)`

It may be reseting the datasource on each postback.

Answer (score -1):

try this?

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(some_query);
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Refresh() cannot be used for refreshing data!