# How I Reload Datagridview data while insert or update data in .net form application and database is in access database?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net, ms-access-2007

I have a desktop application project. In entry page a datagridview shows the existing items in database. Now when I entry new Item I want to insert it directly in datagridview. That mean I want to reload/refresh datagridview. My database is in MS Access.

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    using (OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(conn))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ID,Name from GroupDetails where comID='" + label1.Text + "'", con);
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID,Name from GroupDetails where comID='" + label1.Text + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        //SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        return dt;
    }
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn);
    con.Open();
    //SqlCommand cmd;
    try
    {
        string query = "insert into GroupDetails (ID,Name) values(@ID,@Name)";
        // cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtName.Text);
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(i!=0)
        {
            dataGridGroup.DataSource = GetData();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

[Note: When I use sql database then it works fine.]

Comment: possible duplicate of [why doesn't datagridview refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108006/why-doesnt-datagridview-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

The **dbDataAdapterClass** (the one that OleDbDataAdapter inherits from) has a SelectCommand, UpdateCommand and InsertCommand. These are responsible for **select, update, and insert** when you explicit call any of the methods (for example update ;) ). Since in your code, you never provide the command that explain how to do the update, the dataadapter doesn't know how to do it.

so fulfill the requirements, adding an update command to the adapter.

```
dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
```

Add below code after above line, OleDbCommandBuilder will generate commands for you.

```
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataadapter);
```

[This](http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database) tutorial should help you out.

Comment: Already I used this. but there is no change in datagridview. When I reopen this form then datagridview take update.